# Set and test bandwidth on NGINX server

Tags: nginx, bandwidth

I am using NGINX and i want to control the number of connections and the bandwidth for each user . This is what offers NGINX for this

```
limit_rate 150k;
```

where 150k is some value for limit rate, i want this limit_rate to be variable but this directive accpet only values.

The second part of my question is how to test the bandwidth excess. Are they any tools to target the server with requests until exceeding bandwidth

Comment: May I ask, this variable value depends on what ?

Comment: I want it to be set by server administrator before running the server, actually i found `$limit_rate` that can take a variable value but still can't figure how to test  bandwidth excess on my server

Comment: if by excess you mean you want to measure the bandwidth that the server is currently using, I would suggest installing `vnstat` and run the command `vnstat -l`